# onFocusChange not triggered in SwiftUI tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tvos

I am trying to set `onFocusChange` and click action function on a view. But `onFocusChange` is never called.

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
        ForEach(self.videos, id: \.id) { video in
            
            Button(action: {
                print("clicked")
            }){
                ItemView(vid: video)
                    .cornerRadius(5).padding(1)
            }.focusable(true, onFocusChange: {
                hasFocus in
                print("focused")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

If I move the button view inside the `ItemView()`, the `onFocusChange` works but the click action doesn't.

Comment: `focusable` works for views which are by default inactive, so buttons, which are already focusable by nature, is out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I read that too. But can I set click event for VStack?

Comment: I tried NavigationLink. But onFocusChange didn't work with that either.

Comment: NavigationLink in SwiftUI is kind of Button, so it is expected.

Comment: So is there any way to get around this limitation?

Comment: Ok, let's step back... instead of trying to make work what is not work, let's consider what do you want to do on that callback... because there might be alternate way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal the question is unclear, but here is a simple demo of alternate approach to have managed focused & button click using custom button style. Maybe this will be helpful.

Tested with Xcode 12 / tvOS 14 (Simulator) - compare regular button vs custom button

[image]

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 1.2 : 1)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var focused = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print(">>>> custom button")
            }) { LabelView() }.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())

            Button("Regular Button") {
                print(">> regular button")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LabelView: View {
    @Environment(\.isFocused) var focused: Bool
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(focused ? .blue : .gray)
            .overlay(Text("Title").foregroundColor(.white))
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you response but `onTapGesture` is not available in tvOS.

Comment: see udpated with some alternate approach

Comment: Thank you @Asperi. This solution works. The only downside is that it requires iOS 14+.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for tvOS 13?