# Is it possible to subscribe to a view's focus status from a viewModel?

Tags: swiftui, tvos, combine

I am currently creating a SwiftUI tvOS UI component that is meant to be autonomous (for possible reuse). We can think of it as a small module. The container view that will inject this component needs to know where the focus is within that component. (The container will change other UI elements based on this focus state).

I tried:

- adding the modifier `focusable` on the view that gets the focus

```
            .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focused in
                if focused {
                    aClosure() // or a publisher?
                }
            })
```

but then the button style doesn't react to the focus state. (The style changes like this: `view.background(isFocused ? buttonStyle.backgroundColor.active : buttonStyle.backgroundColor.normal)`, which is hooked to `@Environment(\.isFocused) var isFocused`).

- That method, as you might point out, is deprecated starting tvOS 15, but the suggested alternatives don't fill my need. (You can point out I'm wrong about this, though!)
- The .isFocused environment var (`@Environment(\.isFocused) var isFocused`) doesn't seem to change outside of a view modifier (which would make sense given its purpose, but I'm not 100% sure about this)
  - I tried hooking up to the notifications of the focus, but that block will execute at each focus change for every view that registers to that notification. Also, because we're dealing with structs, managing identity comparisons is not trivial and I need an info from the view that gets the focus. Here's code:

```
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIFocusSystem.didUpdateNotification,
                                               object: nil,
                                               queue: OperationQueue.main) { notification in
            
            if let context = notification.userInfo?["UIFocusUpdateContextKey"] as? UIFocusUpdateContext {
                print("[Focus] context next item: \(context.nextFocusedItem)")
                someCompletionBlock()
            }
        }
```

- Focus state (`@FocusState`) is tvOS 15+ and I need tvOS 14 compatibility. Also, I tried to hook a `didSet` block to it but did not get executed. Is it normal?

We thought the solution could be to create our own Property Wrapper but it's not even clear how to go about it. I guess it would need to listen to a focus property anyway?

Can a Combine Publisher "listen" to changes in focus, so that change can be propagated to the correct container? Something in the spirit of:

```
    var onFocusPublisher: Publisher<Bool, Never> {
        $isFocused // where isFocused is the @Environment var
    }
```

Thank you for any feedback / suggestions / possible answers!

Note: I added `-UIFocusLoggingEnabled YES` to the passed arguments list of my scheme and I confirmed the view gets the focus as expected.

Comment: Not clear what you really want to achieve. Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63172333/12299030?

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear... Basically some other parts of a UIViewController that contains this view will react to what is on Focus. The question you linked is pertinent and made me try some alternatives I haven't thought of yet but does not seem to answer my question. Thank you any way!

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working is to use the [`onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) function from the button custom style body.

This way, the visual behaviour keeps working (i.e. `view.background(isFocused ? buttonStyle.backgroundColor.active : buttonStyle.backgroundColor.normal)` reacts to changes appropriately, and I can communicate the focus state using closures from this view up to the container.

And it is a non-deprecated tvOS 14+ API, which is a plus.

The major downside of this approach is that the ButtonStyle struct now has 2 responsibilities. For now I'll live with this less-clean method.